# Ruby on Rails: Sortable Table Columns Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui-sortable, railscasts

I'm trying to follow a railcasts tutorial on [Sortable Table Columns](http://railscasts.com/episodes/228-sortable-table-columns?view=asciicast), and I am getting an error.

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: name: SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects"  ORDER BY name asc

I've followed the instructions in the tutorial, the only thing that has changed is the table size, name and column names.

Here is my search view:

```
<table class = "pretty">
 <tr>
<th><%= sortable "project_name", "Project name" %> </th>
<th><%= sortable "client", "Client" %></th>
<th>Exception pm</th>
<th>Project owner</th>
<th>Tech</th>
<th>Role</th>
<th>Industry</th>
<th>Financials</th>
<th>Business div</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Start date</th>
<th>End date</th>
<th>Entry date</th>
<th>Edited date</th>
<th>Summary</th>
<th>Lessons learned</th>
<th>Customer benifits</th>
<th>Keywords</th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
<th></th>
</tr>

<% @projects.each do |t| %>
<tr>
<td><%= t.project_name %></td>
<td><%= t.client %></td>
<td><%= t.exception_pm %></td>
<td><%= t.project_owner %></td>
<td><%= t.tech %></td>
<td><%= t.role %></td>
<td><%= t.industry %></td>
<td><%= t.financials %></td>
<td><%= t.business_div %></td>
<td><%= t.status %></td>
<td><%= t.start_date %></td>
<td><%= t.end_date %></td>
<td><%= t.entry_date %></td>
<td><%= t.edited_date %></td>
<td><%= t.summary %></td>
<td><%= t.lessons_learned %></td>
<td><%= t.customer_benifits %></td>
<td><%= t.keywords %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Show', project %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_project_path(project) %></td>
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', project, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
</tr>
<% end %>
</table>
```

EDIT:

This is my db schema

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 20120717141952) do

create_table "projects", :force => true do |t|
t.string   "project_name"
t.string   "client"
t.string   "exception_pm"
t.string   "project_owner"
t.string   "tech"
t.string   "role"
t.string   "industry"
t.string   "financials"
t.string   "business_div"
t.string   "status"
t.date     "start_date"
t.date     "end_date"
t.datetime "entry_date"
t.datetime "edited_date"
t.text     "summary"
t.text     "lessons_learned"
t.text     "customer_benifits"
t.text     "keywords"
t.datetime "created_at",        :null => false
t.datetime "updated_at",        :null => false
end

end
```

Any ideas? Any help at all will be appreciated. I am new to ruby on rails, so go easy :)

Comment: Looks like there is no column name in the database table. Please show us your db/schema.rb (or the relevant parts).

Comment: Added the db schema. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't understand that I had to name the default column when going through the tutorial. My default column was meant to be project_name, instead of name.

Thanks